# получение адреса

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Есть блоки:

```
<div class="gallery-photos-block">
  <div class="gallery-photos-block-active"></div>
    <img src="/img/gallery/2.jpg" class="alignnone">
</div>
```

и есть код:

```
$(".gallery-photos-block").click(function(){
        var img = $(this);
        var src = img.attr('src');
```

где при клике должен происходить поиск `src` картинки.

`var img = $(this);` ищет в самом блоке (то есть после тега класс).

Как изменить код так, чтобы атрибут `src` искался в теге `img` внутри блока, на который кликнули, а не в самом блоке?

Comment: Раз десять прочитал вопрос и не понял. `Как задать ему,` - задать кому? Задать что? Задать где?

Comment: Изменил немного)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Решение:

```
$(".gallery-photos-block").on('click', function () {
    var img = $(this).find('img');
    var src = img.attr('src');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Обычно используют **[find](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA_%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85)**:

```js
$(".gallery-photos-block").click(function(){
    var img = $(this).find('img'); // $('img', this)
    var src = img.attr('src');
    console.log(src);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="gallery-photos-block">
  clickable text
  <div class="gallery-photos-block-active"></div>
    <img src="/img/gallery/2.jpg" class="alignnone">
</div>
```

Можно через **[children](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA_%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%85_%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2)**:

```js
$(".gallery-photos-block").click(function(){
    var img = $(this).children('img');
    var src = img.attr('src');
    console.log(src);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="gallery-photos-block">
  clickable text
  <div class="gallery-photos-block-active"></div>
    <img src="/img/gallery/2.jpg" class="alignnone">
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое))

Comment: а можно `var src = $('img', this).attr('src');`

Answer (score 0):

Вы хотите получить `src` картинки? Ну тогда получайте `src` картинки, а не пытайтесь найти `src` у `div`.

```
$(".gallery-photos-block").click(function(){
        var src = $(this).find.('.alignnone').attr('.src');
}
```

Comment: я не особо в джаве ))
логику пониаю а вот теги не знаю какие есть и за что они отвечают)

Comment: [Java](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java) и [JavaScript](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript) абсолютно разные языки

Comment: А тут так вообще jquery )